# How to read the cedict (a space separated file) with regex groups?

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, unicode, nlp

[CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=cc-cedict) is a resource for Chinese text analysis

The file plaintext file looks like this:

```
# CC-CEDICT
# Community maintained free Chinese-English dictionary.
# 
# Published by MDBG
% % [pa1] /percent (Tw)/
21三體綜合症 21三体综合症 [er4 shi2 yi1 san1 ti3 zong1 he2 zheng4] /trisomy/Down's syndrome/
3C 3C [san1 C] /abbr. for computers, communications, and consumer electronics/China Compulsory Certificate (CCC)/
3P 3P [san1 P] /(slang) threesome/
A A [A] /(slang) (Tw) to steal/
```

There are 4 columns to the files and they are separated by spaces. Any spaces after the 4th is considered as one. Lines that starts with `#` needs to be skipped.

E.g. for the line:

> 3C 3C [san1 C] /abbr. for computers, communications, and consumer electronics/China Compulsory Certificate (CCC)/

The content in the columns would be

- 3C
- 3C
- [san1 C]
- /abbr. for computers, communications, and consumer electronics/China Compulsory Certificate (CCC)/

Currently to read the file I've been tried using a mix of `str.split` and `re.findall` and skipping lines by `str.startswith()`, i.e.:

```
import re
from collections import namedtuple


DictEntry = namedtuple('Dictionary', 'traditional simplified pinyin glosses')

dictfile = 'cedict_ts.u8'
cedict = {}

with open(dictfile, 'r', encoding='utf8') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        if line.startswith('#'):
            continue
        # Note: lines are NOT separated by tabs.
        line = line.strip()
        trad, sim, *stuff = line.split()
        pinyin = re.findall(r'\[([^]]*)\]',line)[0]
        glosses = re.findall(r'\/.*\/', line)[0].strip('/').split('/')
        entry = DictEntry(traditional=trad, simplified=sim, pinyin=pinyin, glosses=glosses)
        cedict[sim] = entry
```

It looks like the str and regex operations can be simiplified into a single regex and the columns can be extracted using groups. **How to read the cedict (a space separated file) with regex groups?**

---

I've also tried this regex with 4 groups:

```
(.*)\s(.*)\s(\[([^]]*)\])\s(\/.*\/)
```

But somehow the first `(.*)\s` is greedy and it captures the whole line: https://regex101.com/r/1c0O0E/1

---

I've tried this:

```
.+\s(\[([^]]*)\])\s(\/.*\/)
```

And the first `.+\s` captures till it sees `[`. But that means that I'll have to use `str.split()` to get the first 2 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "non-space" (`\S`) instead of just "anything" (`.`):

```
^(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\[[^]]+\])\s+(\/.*\/)$
```

I also added begin-of-text and end-of-test anchors (`^` & `$`) to rule out any lines not matching the required pattern (e.g. comment lines).

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/0QNzVi/3

Comment: `^(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\[[^]]+\])\s+(\/[^]]+\/$)` for including the `[]` and `//`. https://regex101.com/r/0QNzVi/2

Comment: @MYGz, Yes, that's right. I just was a bit confused by the OP samples. Fixing the answer. Thanks

Comment: Would adding `\n$` work to avoid stripping the final `\n` character? Or that'll be redundant?

Comment: @MYGz, shouldn't it be `^(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+\[([^]]+)\]\s+\/([^]]+)\/$` ?